Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle. MAC M4 Flutter
There seems to be other similar questions but this one is on the new Mac M4.
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-all.zip

Ive followed through on finding a gradle that is apparently compatible with Java 23 but still getting this error
java --version 
java 23.0.1 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)

Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle. 


version not mentioned in the Docs that seems to work
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

I then opened the android folder of the flutter project in Android Studio and it updated gradle files and built successfully.

Formally, the first Gradle version to support Java 23 is Gradle 8.10, see their compatibility matrix.
